# Screen colour when sliding

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

I just got a Samsung Galaxy 2 and when I slide the screen and when there is nothing more to scroll, I get blue screen at the edge. Is this normal? The phone is working fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, totally normal. This is the UI's way of telling you that you've reached the edge.